# Gradle DSL method not found: 'buildConfigField()'

Tags: android, gradle

I had this gradle error

Error:(21, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'buildConfigField()'
Possible causes:

```
<ul><li>The project 'Sunshine' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.

<a href="openGradleSettings">Gradle settings</a></li><li>The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.

<a href="apply.gradle.plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a></li>
```

my build.gradle code is here

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.boxerrebellion.sunshine.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildTypes.each {
         it.buildConfigField 'String', 'OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
}
```

anyone having any idea?
thanks in advance

Comment: Use  it.buildConfigField 'String', 'OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY' . 'xxxxxx' ad described by Blackbelt answer.

Answer (score 6):

This is a very annoying *how gradle works* issue. For reference:

`buildConfigField("String", "API_BASE_URL", "https://x.x.x.com/v2/")`

Will result in:

[image]

It's necessary to apply escaped quotes like:

`buildConfigField("String", "API_BASE_URL", "\"https://x.x.x.com/v2/\"")`

Answer (score 5):

`buildConfigField` is defined like follows

```
void buildConfigField(String type, String name, String value)
```

it expects a type, the name of the field and the value. If have the first two, not the third one. You can read more about it [here](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType:buildConfigField(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Answer (score 3):

just add this in `defaultConfig` block :

```
  buildConfigField("String", "API_BASE_URL", "https://x.x.x.com/v2/")
```

Comment: The defaultConfig is disabled by default, any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

Add 'OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY' value on build.gradle code

```
 buildTypes.each {
         it.buildConfigField 'String', 'OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY', 'xxxx'
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

You might be missing the parenthisis while copy pasting your MyOpenWeatherAPIKey

Initally it looks like

```
buildTypes.each {
    it.buildConfigField 'String', 'OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY', MyOpenWeatherAPIKey
}
```

After you copy your MyOpenWeatherAPIKey from https://home.openweathermap.org/api_keys it should like

```
buildTypes.each {
    it.buildConfigField 'String', 'OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
}
```